# Which of the following options specifies the default matrix

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

Which of the following options specifies the default matrix of the linear image $T$ corresponding to counterclockwise rotation $\pi/6$ radians followed by mirroring in the $y$-axis?

**Options:**

1. $\dfrac12\begin{bmatrix}-\sqrt3&1\\1&\sqrt3\end{bmatrix}$
2. $\dfrac12\begin{bmatrix}-\sqrt3&-1\\-1&\sqrt3\end{bmatrix}$
3. $\dfrac12\begin{bmatrix}1&\sqrt3\\\sqrt3&-1\end{bmatrix}$
4. $\dfrac12\begin{bmatrix}1&-\sqrt3\\-\sqrt3&-1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: What have you tried? Maybe you can multiply these matrices (in your mind) by a simple representation of a point, and see where it ends up.

Comment: Should I just multiply 1/2 to the different matrices and then add like in case 1:         -sqrt(3)/2 +1/2 and 1/2+sqrt(3)/2 or am I thinking wrong?

Comment: Yes, that's how matrix multiplication works. The terms look good because $\cos{\frac{\pi}{6}} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ etc.

Comment: could you show me how I should determine which of the options that are correct?

Answer (score 0):

Counter-clockwise rotation by angle $\theta$ in the $xy$-plane is represented by the rotation matrix
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\cos{\theta} & -\sin{\theta}\\
\sin{\theta} & \cos{\theta}
\end{array}
\right]
$$
In other words, if you have a point or vector, whose (end) point is represented by a column vector, multiplying by this matrix from the left rotates the point or vector around the origin.

The problem definition also mentions mirroring about the line $y=0$. This corresponds to just flipping the sign of the $x$-coordinate, so the representative matrix of this operation is
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
-1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right]
$$
Putting this together, and plugging in $\theta=\frac{\pi}{6}$ results in
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
-1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\cos{\theta} & -\sin{\theta}\\
\sin{\theta} & \cos{\theta}
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
-\cos{\theta} & \sin{\theta}\\
\sin{\theta} & \cos{\theta}
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
\end{array}
\right]
$$
Therefore, the correct answer is the first option on the list.